# Как сделать вертикальную прокрутку?

Tags: css

Имеется выпадающее меню. При ховере на любом из пунктов меню, если на одном уровне пунктов меню много и они заходят внизу за экран, то должна появиться вертикальная прокрутка.  https://jsfiddle.net/vosh67kh/3/
А сейчас при ховере появляется горизонтальная прокрутка
**P.S. добавлю, что все нижеприведённые ответы не соответствуют вопросу**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
P.S. добавлю, что `overflow-x:hidden;` не решает эту проблему
т.е. выпадающее меню должно быть на всех уровнях, а сейчас вместо выпадающего меню появляется гор-я прокрутка

```css
      * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

       ul {
            list-style: none;
        }

        #top-menu-nav, #top-menu {
            line-height: 0;
        }

        #main-header {
            transition: background-color 0.4s, color 0.4s, transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
        }
        .nav{
          margin-top: 20px;
        }
        .nav li {
            position: relative;
            line-height: 1em;
        }

        .nav li li {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0 20px;
        }

        .nav li li {
            position: relative;
            line-height: 2em;
        }

        #top-menu li {
            word-wrap: break-word;
        }

        #top-menu li {
            display: inline-block;
            padding-right: 22px;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        #top-menu > li:last-child {
            padding-right: 0px;
        }

        a {
            color: #2ea3f2;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .nav li li a, .et_mobile_menu li a {
            font-size: 14px;
            transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
        }

        #top-menu a {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
            text-decoration: none;
            transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        }

        #top-menu li a {
            font-size: 13px;
        }

        .nav li ul {
            position: absolute;
            padding: 20px 0;
        }

        .nav li:hover {
            visibility: inherit;
        }

        .nav li:hover > ul {
            display:block;
        }

        .nav li ul {
            display:none;
            z-index: 9999;
            width: 240px;
            border-top: 3px solid #2ea3f2;
            background: #fff;
            box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }

        .nav li ul {
            text-align: left;
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        }

        .nav li ul {
            border-color: #48a400;
        }

        .nav ul {
            overflow-y: scroll;
            height:80vh;
        }

        .nav li li ul {
            z-index: 1000;
            top: -23px;
            left: 240px;
        }

        #top-menu li li {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0 20px;
        }

        #top-menu li li a {
            width: 200px;
            padding: 6px 20px;
        }

        #top-menu li .menu-item-has-children > a:first-child::after {
            top: 6px;
            right: 20px;
        }
```

```html
<nav id="top-menu-nav">
    <ul class="nav" id="top-menu">
        <li class="menu-item"
            id="menu-item-766"><a href="#">Диагностика</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item"><a
                        href="#">Ультразвуковая
                    диагностика</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">УЗИ
                            на определение пола ребенка</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Диагностика</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">УЗИ
                            беременности 4D с допплерометрией</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">УЗИ
                            беременности III триместр</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">УЗИ
                            беременности II триместр</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">УЗИ
                            беременности I триместр</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">УЗИ
                            для определения беременности</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">УЗИ
                            лонного сочленения</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">УЗИ
                            матки</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">УЗИ
                            органов малого таза</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">УЗИ
                            легких</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">УЗИ
                            на наличие свободной жидкости</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">УЗИ
                            селезенки</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">УЗИ
                            поджелудочной железы</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">УЗИ
                            желчного пузыря</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">УЗИ
                            печени</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">УЗИ
                            брюшной полости</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">УЗИ
                            органов мошонки</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">ТРУЗИ
                            предстательной железы</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">УЗИ
                            остаточной мочи</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">УЗИ
                            мочевого пузыря</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Анализы</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Взрослое
                            отделение</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Отделения</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Детское
                            отделение</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">УЗИ
                            почек</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Анализы</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Анализы</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Анализы</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Анализы</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Анализы</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Анализы</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Анализы</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Анализы</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Анализы</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Анализы</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Анализы</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Анализы</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Анализы</a>
                </li>


            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">О центре</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Новости</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a
                        href="#">Врачи</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a
                        href="#">Политика
                    конфиденциальности</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a
                        href="#">Нормативные
                    акты</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Лицензии</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a
                        href="#">Контролирующие
                    органы</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a
                        href="#">Клятва
                    Гиппократа</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Реквизиты</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Вакансии</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a
                        href="#">Расписание
                    врачей</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item"
            id="menu-item-769"><a href="#">Услуги</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item"><a
                        href="#">Массаж</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a
                        href="#">Вакцинопрофилактика</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item"
            id="menu-item-543"><a href="#">Цены</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"
            id="menu-item-363"><a href="#">Акции</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"
            id="menu-item-364"><a href="#">Программы</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item"><a
                        href="#">Ведение
                    беременности</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a
                        href="#">Дети до 1
                    года</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a
                        href="#">Дети от 1 до
                    3</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a
                        href="#">Дети от 4 до
                    7</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Школьники</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item"
            id="menu-item-366"><a href="#">Отделения</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item"><a
                        href="#">Взрослое
                    отделение</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a
                        href="#">Детское
                    отделение</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item"
            id="menu-item-368"><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: я так понял это очень сложный вопрос? Уже две темы создал, никто ещё не подсказал

Comment: нижеприведённые ответы не соответствуют вопросу

Comment: да, сложный. к сожалению, задан не лучшим образом, поэтому притягивает потенциально полезные ответы, которые в конкретном случае не срабатывают.

Answer (score 1):

Что бы скролл появлялся когда:

> При ховере на любом из пунктов меню, если на одном уровне пунктов меню много и они заходят внизу за экран, то должна появиться вертикальная прокрутка.

Подправьте `.nav ul` на

```
.nav ul {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 80vh;
}
```

Чтобы убрать горизонтальный скролл в `#top-menu li li a` добавьте:

```
#top-menu li li a {
    ...
    width: 100%;
    ...  
}
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
font,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

article,
aside,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

#top-menu-nav,
#top-menu {
  line-height: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1080px;
  margin: auto;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}

.clearfix::after {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  clear: both;
  height: 0px;
  font-size: 0px;
  content: " ";
}

.clearfix::after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0px;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0px;
}

#main-header {
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s, color 0.4s, transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.4s, color 0.4s, transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.4s, color 0.4s, transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

.nav li {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.nav li li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.nav li li {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 2em;
}

#et-secondary-menu li,
#top-menu li {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#top-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 22px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#top-menu > li:last-child {
  padding-right: 0px;
}

a {
  color: #2ea3f2;
  text-decoration: none;
}

:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.et_color_scheme_green a {
  color: #7cc68d;
}

.page_item a {
  font-weight: 400 !important;
}

.nav li li a,
.et_mobile_menu li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#top-menu a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

#top-menu li a {
  font-size: 13px;
}

.nav li ul {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.nav li:hover {
  visibility: inherit;
}

.nav li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

.nav li ul {
  display: none;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 240px;
  border-top: 3px solid #2ea3f2;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.nav li ul {
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.nav li ul {
  border-color: #48a400;
}

.nav ul {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 80vh;
}

.nav li li ul {
  z-index: 1000;
  top: -23px;
  left: 240px;
}

#top-menu li li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

#top-menu li li a {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 20px;
}

#top-menu li .menu-item-has-children > a:first-child::after {
  top: 6px;
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="top-menu-nav">
  <ul class="nav" id="top-menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-340" id="menu-item-340"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/o-tsentre/">О центре</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-367" id="menu-item-367"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/o-tsentre/novosti/">Новости</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-386" id="menu-item-386"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/o-tsentre/nashi-doktora/">Врачи</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-389" id="menu-item-389"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/o-tsentre/politika-konfidentsialnosti/">Политика
                    конфиденциальности</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-402" id="menu-item-402"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/o-tsentre/normativnye-akty/">Нормативные
                    акты</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-711" id="menu-item-711"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/o-tsentre/litsenzii/">Лицензии</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-410" id="menu-item-410"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/o-tsentre/kontroliruyushhie-organy/">Контролирующие
                    органы</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-420" id="menu-item-420"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/o-tsentre/klyatva-gippokrata/">Клятва
                    Гиппократа</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-426" id="menu-item-426"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/o-tsentre/rekvizity/">Реквизиты</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-373" id="menu-item-373"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/o-tsentre/vakansii/">Вакансии</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-812" id="menu-item-812"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/o-tsentre/raspisanie-vrachej/">Расписание
                    врачей</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-769" id="menu-item-769"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/uslugi/">Услуги</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-510" id="menu-item-510"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/uslugi/massazh/">Массаж</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-512" id="menu-item-512"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/uslugi/vaktsinoprofilaktika/">Вакцинопрофилактика</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current-page-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-766" id="menu-item-766"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/">Диагностика</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-878" id="menu-item-878"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/analizy/">Анализы</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-878" id="menu-item-878"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/analizy/">Анализы</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-878" id="menu-item-878"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/analizy/">Анализы</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-878" id="menu-item-878"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/analizy/">Анализы</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-878" id="menu-item-878"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/analizy/">Анализы</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-878" id="menu-item-878"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/analizy/">Анализы</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-878" id="menu-item-878"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/analizy/">Анализы</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-878" id="menu-item-878"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/analizy/">Анализы</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-878" id="menu-item-878"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/analizy/">Анализы</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-878" id="menu-item-878"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/analizy/">Анализы</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-878" id="menu-item-878"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/analizy/">Анализы</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-878" id="menu-item-878"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/analizy/">Анализы</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-878" id="menu-item-878"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/analizy/">Анализы</a>
        </li>

        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-506 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-511" id="menu-item-511"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/ultrazvukovaya-diagnostika/">Ультразвуковая
                    диагностика</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1087" id="menu-item-1087"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/ultrazvukovaya-diagnostika/uzi-na-opredelenie-pola-rebenka/">УЗИ
                            на определение пола ребенка</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor current-page-parent menu-item-1397" id="menu-item-1397"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/">Диагностика</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1084" id="menu-item-1084"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/ultrazvukovaya-diagnostika/uzi-beremennosti-4d/">УЗИ
                            беременности 4D с допплерометрией</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1079" id="menu-item-1079"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/ultrazvukovaya-diagnostika/uzi-beremennosti-3-trimestr/">УЗИ
                            беременности III триместр</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1047" id="menu-item-1047"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/ultrazvukovaya-diagnostika/uzi-beremennosti-ii-trimestr/">УЗИ
                            беременности II триместр</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1042" id="menu-item-1042"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/ultrazvukovaya-diagnostika/uzi-beremennosti-na-rannih-srokah/">УЗИ
                            беременности I триместр</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1036" id="menu-item-1036"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/ultrazvukovaya-diagnostika/uzi-dlya-opredeleniya-beremennosti/">УЗИ
                            для определения беременности</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1033" id="menu-item-1033"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/ultrazvukovaya-diagnostika/uzi-lonnogo-sochleneniya/">УЗИ
                            лонного сочленения</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1028" id="menu-item-1028"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/ultrazvukovaya-diagnostika/uzi-matki/">УЗИ
                            матки</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1023" id="menu-item-1023"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/ultrazvukovaya-diagnostika/uzi-organov-malogo-taza/">УЗИ
                            органов малого таза</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1015" id="menu-item-1015"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/ultrazvukovaya-diagnostika/uzi-plevralnoj-polosti/">УЗИ
                            легких</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1012" id="menu-item-1012"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/ultrazvukovaya-diagnostika/uzi-na-nalichie-svobodnoj-zhidkosti/">УЗИ
                            на наличие свободной жидкости</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-913" id="menu-item-913"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/ultrazvukovaya-diagnostika/uzi-selezenki/">УЗИ
                            селезенки</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-908" id="menu-item-908"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/ultrazvukovaya-diagnostika/uzi-podzheludochnoj-zhelezy/">УЗИ
                            поджелудочной железы</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-903" id="menu-item-903"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/ultrazvukovaya-diagnostika/uzi-zhelchnogo-puzyrya/">УЗИ
                            желчного пузыря</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-894" id="menu-item-894"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/ultrazvukovaya-diagnostika/uzi-pecheni/">УЗИ
                            печени</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-887" id="menu-item-887"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/ultrazvukovaya-diagnostika/uzi-bryushnoj-polosti/">УЗИ
                            брюшной полости</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1225" id="menu-item-1225"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/ultrazvukovaya-diagnostika/uzi-organov-moshonki/">УЗИ
                            органов мошонки</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1226" id="menu-item-1226"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/ultrazvukovaya-diagnostika/truzi-predstatelnoj-zhelezy/">ТРУЗИ
                            предстательной железы</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1227" id="menu-item-1227"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/ultrazvukovaya-diagnostika/uzi-ostatochnoj-mochi/">УЗИ
                            остаточной мочи</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1228" id="menu-item-1228"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/ultrazvukovaya-diagnostika/uzi-mochevogo-puzyrya/">УЗИ
                            мочевого пузыря</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1398" id="menu-item-1398"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/analizy/">Анализы</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1400" id="menu-item-1400"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/otdeleniya/vzrosloe-otdelenie/">Взрослое
                            отделение</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1399" id="menu-item-1399"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/otdeleniya/">Отделения</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1401" id="menu-item-1401"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/otdeleniya/detskoe-otdelenie/">Детское
                            отделение</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1229" id="menu-item-1229"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/diagnostika/ultrazvukovaya-diagnostika/uzi-pochek/">УЗИ
                            почек</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-543" id="menu-item-543"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/tsenu/">Цены</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-363" id="menu-item-363"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/aktsii/">Акции</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-364" id="menu-item-364"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/programmy/">Программы</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-478" id="menu-item-478"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/programmy/vedenie-beremennosti/">Ведение
                    беременности</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-477" id="menu-item-477"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/programmy/deti-do-1-goda/">Дети до 1
                    года</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-476" id="menu-item-476"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/programmy/deti-ot-1-do-3/">Дети от 1 до
                    3</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-475" id="menu-item-475"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/programmy/deti-ot-4-do-7/">Дети от 4 до
                    7</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-474" id="menu-item-474"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/programmy/shkolniki/">Школьники</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-366" id="menu-item-366"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/otdeleniya/">Отделения</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-514" id="menu-item-514"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/otdeleniya/vzrosloe-otdelenie/">Взрослое
                    отделение</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-513" id="menu-item-513"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/otdeleniya/detskoe-otdelenie/">Детское
                    отделение</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-368" id="menu-item-368"><a href="http://orangemed.testing-elit.ru/kontakty/">Контакты</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**P.S.**: для точной настройки выпадающего списка поиграйте с `.nav ul {height:80vh}`

Comment: а вы проверяли? не работает

Comment: @word, выполнить код нажмите и посмотрите.

Comment: появляется горизонтальная прокрутка https://c2n.me/3R3tkAE

Comment: проверьте пожалуйста в песочнице, я привёл ссылку https://jsfiddle.net/vosh67kh/3/

Comment: @word, какая именно прокрутка появляется, в выпадающем списке или на страницы?

Comment: а разве вы не проверяли свои пример? появляется горизонтальная прокрутка, и чтобы посмотреть выпадающее меню, нужно прокручивать горизонтальную прокрутку. Я скриншот привел чуть выше

Comment: @word, в хроме не появляется. Какой браузер?

Comment: @Qwertiy, как это не появляется, если появляется в хроме и в других браузерах. Скриншот скинул выше, вот https://clip2net.com/s/3R3tkAE 
 .Вместо выделенного квадрата должно быть выпадающее меню, но его нет из-за гор-й прокрутки

Comment: Надо было уточнять, что надо доскроллить до конца списка и навести мышку на надпись `Ультразвуковая диагностика`, чтобы он появился. Вот сложно было сказать?

Comment: @Qwertiy, извиняюсь, нет, не сложно, просто я выложил куча скриншотов, почему-то решил, что те, кто хочет помочь, они разберутся. Из скриншотов всё понятно.Тем более я не раз упоминал, что из приведённых ответов ничего не получается

Comment: Ну так в сниппете в вопросе скролл есть всегда, а тут его ещё поискать...

Comment: @Qwertiy, есть ли вариант, как решить эту задачу, подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: @word, наверняка есть, но без [mcve] мне разбираться лень...

Comment: так есть же мин-й самодостаточный пример.https://jsfiddle.net/vosh67kh/3/  я не раз приводил ссылку

Comment: @Qwertiy, перенёс выпадающее меню в самый верх https://jsfiddle.net/vosh67kh/7/  https://c2n.me/3R4tRqf

Comment: @word, ну как 449 строк кода для выпадающего меню, из которых 195 - это стили, могут быть _минимальным_ примером? :(

Comment: @Qwertiy, извиняюсь, вот https://jsfiddle.net/vosh67kh/9/ повырезал всё лишнее

Comment: @Qwertiy, Выпадающее меню находится в самом 1м уровне вложенного меню c2n.me/3R4GedO

Comment: @Kniha m видимо автор вопроса не ценит чужое потраченное время на него и ждать благодарности не приходится.  Сочувствую (+)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, спасибо. Но задачу все же не решили на CSS. Вопросы автор четко не умеет задавать:)

Comment: @Kniham так я это и имел ввиду. Пусть вопрос не решён, по причине размытости, нечеткости вопроса,  и галочку нельзя ставить, но где элементарное чувство благодарности или оно адресуется только людям с телепатическими способностями :)

Answer (score 1):

**Нет, сделать это только на css невозможно** по следующей причине.

Если меню третьего уровня будет позиционироваться относительно элемента

- внутри прокручиваемой области, то оно попадёт под прокрутку и не сможет оказаться вне прокручиваемого блока (меню второго уровня).
- снаружи прокручиваемой области, то оно не будет двигаться синхронно с вертикальной прокруткой меню второго уровня.

Рекомендую пойти по второму пути и при помощи js обеспечить синхронность передвижения.

Хотя можно попытаться найти какой-нибудь хак для webkit'ов, в которых можно стилизовать полосу прокрутки. Но в других браузерах точно не взлетит.

Answer (score 0):

Вертикальная прокрутка у Вас по сути уже есть.
Если Вам требуется только вертикальная прокрутка, а горизонтальная должна отсутствовать, попробуйте явно задать у селектора `.nav ul`атрибут `overflow-x` как `hidden`.

Например:

```
.nav ul {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    height:80vh;
}
```

Если вложенные списки с элементами меню открываются сбоку, то их будет не видно, т.к. приведённый код отключает горизонтальную прокрутку полностью (другие варианты пока технически недоступны).

В качестве возможного варианта выхода из положения, можно попробовать убрать отступ у вложенного списка. Но, тут уже смотрите сами смотрите,что Вам больше подходит (в том числе в плане дизайна).

Comment: а вы проверяли этот код? Ваш код вообще не будет давать раскрыться вложенным уровням

Comment: @word, я дополнил ответ. Надеюсь, теперь Вы поймёте как работает `overflow-x` и куда на самом деле "исчезают" вложенные списки. Корень проблемы со списками я Вам тоже указал. Дальше, извините, уже сами.

Comment: А, вообще, только без обид, читайте основы...

Comment: никакой обиды нет, потому-что основы я знаю, а вы даже не проверили свой код, он не работает

Comment: я дал ссылку на песочницу, проверьте пожалуйста свой код перед тем, как давать ответ,  извините ваш код не соответствует вопросу

Comment: Извините и Вы меня, только похоже Вы перепутали ruSO с биржей фриланса. Здесь могут подсказать, дать совет, направить, **если человек сам пытается разобраться**. Если же Ваш вопрос состоит только в том, чтобы получить полностью доработанный и выверенный код, Вам лучше обратиться к фрилансерам. Они Вам за деньги помогут. Ничего личного.

Comment: извините, но ваш ответ не совсем соответствует вопросу. Ваш ответ подходит не для всех уровней вложенности. А то что вы советовали, это я уже до вас давно испробовал, ничего не подходит